# torgen CSRF not working

Tags: php, mysql

I do not know or is the problem, my code does not wroking always  error 1||error 2

```
  <?php
 session_start();
 $token = uniqid(rand(), true);
 $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
 $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();

 ?> 
  <body>
 <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
   <p>Pseudo : 
  <label>
   <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" />
  </label>
 </p>
<p>E-mail : 
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
 </label>
 </p>
 <p>Nom : 
 <label>
  <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" />
 </label>
 <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>"/>
 </p>
  <p>
 <label>
   <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" id="Envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
  </label>
 </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know or is the problem, my code does not wroking always  error 1 ||error2 
I want to secure my site and I do not know how to use this torgen please help me

```
 <?php
```

session_start();

```
if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && isset($_SESSION['token_time']) && 
 isset($_POST['token']))
  {

 if($_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'])
 {

    $timestamp_ancien = time() - (15*60);
    //Si le jeton n'est pas expiré
    if($_SESSION['token_time'] >= $timestamp_ancien)
    {
        //here Instruction  


     }else{echo"error3";}
    }else{echo"error2";}
    }else{echo"error1";}
  ?>
```

Comment: you need `session_start();` at the beginning of your php script as well.

Comment: yes I forgot here but still the problem

Comment: is your HTML and PHP in 2 different files?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. I ran it and it works. What I suggest you do to help with debugging is that you output the session and POST variables. I suspect that the first page may be loaded again somehow and your session token does not match your POST token.

Comment: Echo $ _POST ['token'] and echo $ token, I think different I do not know why!

Comment: Gaurav raises a good point. I assumed you had 2 different pages and omitted the name of the 2nd page in the action. If you're running it all on the same page, you'll have the issues he is describing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have not declared action that means form is going to post on same page.
2. So for point 1 your code to generate token is run every time request coming on the page and hence token changes every time in the session but remain at earlier value in $_POST and error2 is thrown.
3. You have not checked the method and $_POST variable that's why you are getting error1

please try below:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 function generate_token(){
    $token = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
 }


 //avoid putting script at bottom until required
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST)){
if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && isset($_SESSION['token_time']) && 
 isset($_POST['token']))
  {

 if($_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'])
 {

    $timestamp_ancien = time() - (15*60);
    //Si le jeton n'est pas expiré
    if($_SESSION['token_time'] >= $timestamp_ancien)
    {
        //here Instruction  
        generate_token();//for next call


     }else{echo"error3";}
    }else{echo"error2";}
    }else{echo"error1";}
}
generate_token();
  ?>
  <body>
 <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
   <p>Pseudo : 
  <label>
   <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" />
  </label>
 </p>
<p>E-mail : 
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
 </label>
 </p>
 <p>Nom : 
 <label>
  <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" />
 </label>
 <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token'];?>"/>
 </p>
  <p>
 <label>
   <input type="submit" name="Envoyer" id="Envoyer" value="Envoyer" />
  </label>
 </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Now what happens is your function will be called every time page loads but post data will have the comparision and manipulation at earlier state.**

** please correct me if I understood anything wrong.**